# boost::asio blocks std::cout when reading from serial port

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio, cout

I'm using `boost::asio` to read from a serial port. I continuously read from the serial port and print it out through `std::cout`. But some strange things happens.

I'm using `TimeoutSerial` class from [here](http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html). My code goes like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TimeoutSerial.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){  
  TimeoutSerial serial;

  serial.open("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600 );      
  serial.setTimeout(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));

  char c = '0';
  while(true){
    try{
      serial.read( &c, 1 );
      cout << c;
    }catch( std::runtime_error err ){
      cout << "Error: " << err.what()<< endl;
    }
  }         
  return 0;
}
```

I get no output and I have no idea why. When I change `cout << c;` to `cout << c << endl;` I get the output I want but each character is on a new line which is undesirable.

So can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cout` is buffered by default, so you need to flush it to display it on your terminal. Using `std::endl` does this implicitly, as will `std::flush()`. Change your loop to

```
while(true) {
    try {
      serial.read( &c, 1 );
      cout << c;
      std::flush( std::cout );
    } catch ( std::runtime_error err ) {
      cout << "Error: " << err.what() << endl;
    }
}
```